# His taste in Cars: Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: knowledge

I cannot understand Grandpa's taste in cars

> He likes BMW Z8  but not Toyota Supra
>
> He likes Ford Mustang Mach 1  but not Dodge Charger
>
> He likes Mercury Cougar XR7  but not Chevy Chevelle SS

Why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your grandpa likes cars that

> were in James Bond. BMW Z8 - World is not enough, Ford mustang - Diamonds are forever, Mercury Cougar - On her majesty's SS

and dislikes cars that

> were in fast and the furious. Toyota Supra, Dodge Charger, Chevy Chevelle SS were all in the original Fast and the Furious

Answer (score 11):

He likes cars with

> names with numbers in them.

Comment: There is a Knowledge Tag on this @C Tomm.

Comment: That doesn't make his answer wrong @DEEM , unless you provide an example that's counter to this. It's not like it's wildly unreasonable. I don't think he should be downvoted.

Comment: Then there could be similar answers that say : He likes the cars that start with B,F and M and not T,D and C. BTW I did not downvote any answers.

Comment: Sure but again, it's not an unreasonable answer. Just an ambiguous puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

> My initial thoughts were that he liked cars to do with animals.
>  A **MUSTANG** is a breed of horse.
>  A **COUGAR** is a big cat.
>  However, the **BMW Z8** is where this theory falls flat, unless the **Z** means a **ZEBRA**...

Answer (score 3):

I'm 100% sure but I do know that

> The BMW Z8 and the Toyota Supra are the same, albeit with a different shell

But can't say the same for the others.

In checking this, I also discovered that.

> All of the cars grandpa likes was driven by James Bond.  Were the others driven by his enemies in the same film?

Answer (score 3):

He likes cars...

> That have an **M** on it.

See:

> B**M**W Z8, Ford **M**ustang **M**ach 1, **M**ercury Cougar XR7
>  No M on Toyota Supra, Dodge Charger, Chevy Chevelle SS

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**

My first guess is

> that your grandpa liked the brand Ford since mercury was founded by
>  Edsel Ford but that didn't tie together to the BMW.

My second guess was

> that your grandpa was around during the first/second world war and he liked the car brands that drove around back then and just translated that to current versions of that brand.
>  BMW made cars (and military armaments) for the Germans and Ford made
>  (mainly) jeeps for the British. Mercury didn't have an active record
>  for that time, however.

Third guess is

> driving comfort.
>  The bmw Z series is catered for comfort for its user where as the
>  Toyota Supra is catered more towards performance.  Same goes for the
>  mercury and the chevy. Not for the Mustang though.

Answer (score 0):

He likes cars ...

> that end in a numeric digit:
>
>  * He likes BMW Z**8** but not Toyota Supra
>  * He likes Ford Mustang Mach **1** but not Dodge Charger
>  * He likes Mercury Cougar XR**7** but not Chevy Chevelle SS

Comment: Unfortunately, @C.Tomm has answered the same thing. :D